# Keras Calling model prediction with different input generate same result?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here, call predict multiple times

```py
    m = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
    for i, (img_id, corr) in enumerate(zip(csv_file['id'], csv_file['corr'])):
        img_filename = os.path.join(data_dir, 'data/piccollage_data/train_imgs/{}.png'.format(img_id))
        img = tf.expand_dims(load_image(img_filename), 0)
        result = m.predict(img, steps=1)
        print ('idx:{} result: {}, gt: {}'.format(i, result, corr))
```

And the results make me very confused:

[image: And the results:]

I tried to find if any questions is similar to this, but I only found it's about training problems [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/46779/23954).

And I also tried other method e.g. change input as dataset (No problem), , another brute solution is reload model every for loop (It's very stupid) and last solution seems using model serving [link](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-ml-models-with-tf-keras-fd975cc0fa27).

So what I want to ask is that "Why the code I wrote above will generate same results"? Can anyone give me clue?

Comment: Have your model been trained on normalized/preprocessed images? If yes, then in test phase you should also do the same normalization and preprocessing steps on the images before feeding them to the model.

Comment: Sure, I ensure I did and I also can successfully run when input is dataset or reloading model every loop.

Comment: Can you please explain "change input as dataset (No problem), , another brute solution is reload model every for loop (It's very stupid)"? Is it working ok with these?